# Pythonic way to sort a nested list with keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, lambda

I have a list as follows :

```
[{"1": {"movie": "0.53"}}, {"2": {"movie": "5.2"}}, {"3": {"movie": "3.2"}}]
```

And I know how to do `t = sorted(new_list, key=lambda i: float(i['1']['movie']), reverse=True)`

but I am unsure on how can i also have the `1` ,`2` , `3` as iteration ^

Comment: So you are asking how to sort the list of dicts by the single `key` of each dict?

Comment: yes, i want to sort based on movie @mapf

Comment: Are the keys of those dicts continuous `ints`?

Comment: the data structure is incorrect.

Comment: I think OP means `[{"1": {"movie": "0.53"}}, {"2": {"movie": "5.2"}}, {"3": {"movie": "3.2"}}]`

Comment: Try: `t = sorted(new_list, key=lambda i: ( float(i['1']['movie']), float(i['2']['movie']) ), reverse=True)` . This uses 1 and 2 but not 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is convert the inner dictionaries to a list from [`dict.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values), select the first value, then access the `"movie"` key. Then pass this as a `float` to the key function of `sorted`:

```
l = [{"1": {"movie": "0.53"}}, {"2": {"movie": "5.2"}}, {"3": {"movie": "3.2"}}]

result = sorted(l, key=lambda x: float(list(x.values())[0]["movie"]))

print(result)
```

Another option is to convert your list of dicts to a list of lists, sort the result from the resulting list [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items), then convert the result back to a list of dicts:

```
l = [{"1": {"movie": "0.53"}}, {"2": {"movie": "5.2"}}, {"3": {"movie": "3.2"}}]

result = [
    dict(l)
    for l in sorted((list(d.items()) for d in l), key=lambda x: float(x[0][1]["movie"]))
]

print(result)
```

Which can also just use a basic [`dict.update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) approach to convert the list of dicts to a nested dict before sorting:

```
l = [{"1": {"movie": "0.53"}}, {"2": {"movie": "5.2"}}, {"3": {"movie": "3.2"}}]

dicts = {}
for d in l:
    dicts.update(d)
# {'1': {'movie': '0.53'}, '2': {'movie': '5.2'}, '3': {'movie': '3.2'}}

result = [{k: v} for k, v in sorted(dicts.items(), key=lambda x: float(x[1]["movie"]))]

print(result)
```

Or if we want to do it in one line, we can make use of [`collections.ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap):

```
from collections import ChainMap

l = [{"1": {"movie": "0.53"}}, {"2": {"movie": "5.2"}}, {"3": {"movie": "3.2"}}]

result = [
    {k: v} for k, v in sorted(ChainMap(*l).items(), key=lambda x: float(x[1]["movie"]))
]

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'1': {'movie': '0.53'}}, {'3': {'movie': '3.2'}}, {'2': {'movie': '5.2'}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Btw the list that you have posted is incorrect in syntax, assuming it to be list of dictionaries. You can sort it like following:

```
new_list = [
    {"1":{"movie": "0.53"}},
    {"2":{"movie": "5.2"}}, 
    {"3":{"movie": "3.2"}}
    ]

t = sorted(new_list, key=lambda x: float(list(x.items())[0][1]['movie']))
```

Output:

```
[{'1': {'movie': '0.53'}}, {'3': {'movie': '3.2'}}, {'2': {'movie': '5.2'}}]
```